# tMatchGroupHadoop_2 component talend

Tags: talend, amazon-emr

I am working with Talend tMatchGroupHadoop component with Amazon EMR cluster,
it is giving an error: "could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1".

Actually data node is running in the AMR cluster.

```
hadoop fsck

..............Status: HEALTHY
 Total size:    315153 B
 Total dirs:    12
 Total files:   14 (Files currently being written: 1)
 Total blocks (validated):      13 (avg. block size 24242 B)
 Minimally replicated blocks:   13 (100.0 %)
 Over-replicated blocks:        0 (0.0 %)
 Under-replicated blocks:       0 (0.0 %)
 Mis-replicated blocks:         0 (0.0 %)
 Default replication factor:    1
 Average block replication:     1.0
 Corrupt blocks:                0
 Missing replicas:              0 (0.0 %)
 Number of data-nodes:          1
 Number of racks:               1
FSCK ended at Mon Sep 08 06:07:58 UTC 2014 in 158 milliseconds
```

I am getting the  following error:

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3645
[statistics] connected
[INFO ]: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Exception in createBlockOutputStream 10.230.30.124:9200 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
[INFO ]: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Abandoning block blk_-3580819895919001579_2135
[INFO ]: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Excluding datanode 10.230.30.124:9200
Exception in component tMatchGroupHadoop_2_GroupOut
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /in could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:701)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:583)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1092)
[WARN ]: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /in could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:701)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:583)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2912)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1092)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2912)

[WARN ]: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Error Recovery for block blk_-3580819895919001579_2135 bad datanode[0] nodes == null
[WARN ]: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Could not get block locations. Source file "/in" - Aborting...
[statistics] disconnected
[ERROR]: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Exception closing file /in : org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /in could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:701)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:583)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /in could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:701)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:583)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1092)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2912)
Job HadoopMatch ended at 17:54 08/09/2014. [exit code=1]
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: Where is the source file location '/in' set? Looks like an there is an issue with source file definition.   (From 'Could not get block locations. Source file "/in" - Aborting.')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to work this, we have to check the option, use **datanode hostname.**
We have do modification in the windows host file
*C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts*

**EC2PublicIP  PrivateDNS**

example :

**10.210.202.106 ip-101-210-141-188.ec2.internal**

then it is working now.